# I cant find usb driver for GigaByte gsmart tuku t2

Tags: android, eclipse, drivers

I searched everywhere and  didn't find anything. I want to use the device (gsmart tuku t2) for `Android` development.But the Eclipse cant't find it.

I checked the USB Debugging option ,so it's fine. The Device Manager of the Windows shows that the driver is not installed.I checked in the support of the product on the site of the manufacturer but it is not there also.

So is it possible that the phone could not be used for debugging even tho there is configuration for development?

I just cant find the driver.

Answer (score -1):

This is links for "GigaByte gsmart tuku t2" usb drivers:

[Tuku T2 Windows XP USB Modem Driver_64bit](http://www.gigabytecm.com/images/sw/Tuku%20T2/GSmart%20Tuku%20T2_Windows%20XP%20USB%20Modem%20Driver_64bit.zip)

[Tuku T2 Windows XP USB Modem Driver_32bit](http://www.gigabytecm.com/images/sw/Tuku%20T2/GSmart%20Tuku%20T2_Windows%20XP%20USB%20Modem%20Driver_32bit.zip)

*

Ore use 
Samsung usb ADB drivers for link with Eclipse and GigaByte gsmart tuku t2.

Do this:

Download Samsung ADB driver: SAMSUNG_USB_Driver_for_Mobile_Phones.zip 
and install.

Then: 
Control panel > Device Manager > Other devices > ?Android > Update Driver Software > Browse My Computer For driwer software > Let me pic from list of device drivers > Android Phone(ore Samsung android) > Next > Samsung > SAMSUNG Android ADB Interface > Next > Yes > Close.

Now go to Eclipse and You will see GigaByte gsmart tuku t2 in Device Chooser.

Do not forget on phone:
USB connection > USB storage (check) 

and: Developer option > USB debugging (check)